# Solutions of $\sin^2\theta = \frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy} $

Tags: trigonometry

If $x$ and $y$ are real, then the equation
$$\sin^2\theta = \frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy}$$
has a solution:

1. for all $x$ and $y$
2. for no $x$ and $y$
3. only when $x \neq y \neq 0$
4. only when $x = y \neq 0$

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you managed to eliminate any of  (A)-(D)?

Comment: Yes, but (1) only.

Comment: Ok, the critical thing you need to notice is that $x,y$ must have the same sign (because a square cannot be negative). But $(x-y)^2\ge0$ with equality iff $x=y$. So we can only get $0\le\sin^2\theta\le1$ by taking $x=y$.

Comment: @JamilAhmed Are you solving any competitive exam books like that of IITJEE because the questions you ask are surely from such books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$(x/y)^2-2(x/y)\sin^2\theta+1=0$$

As $x/y$ is real,the discriminant is $$(2\sin^2\theta)^2-4\ge0\iff\sin^4\theta\ge1\iff\sin^2\theta\ge1\iff\cos^2\theta\le0$$

this is only possible if $\cos^2\theta=0\iff\sin^2\theta=?$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: ...if $sin^2\theta = 1$ this means $(x-y)^2 = 0 $ , i.e. $x = y $. Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

First you need $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$ in order for your fraction $\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2xy}$ to make sense.

Then as $\sin \in [-1,1]$ you need $x^2+y^2 \leq 2xy$ which means:

$x^2 -2xy+y^2 \leq 0$ ie $(x-y)^2 \leq 0$

Therefore you have solutions on $\theta$ only if $x = y \ne 0$, and those solutions are $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2} \pmod \pi$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are not $0$.

We know that $$x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy. \quad (1)$$
Two cases:

- $x>0$ and $y<0$ (or $x<0$ and $y>0$), then $\frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy} < 0$, and you cannot have $\sin^2(\theta) < 0$
- $x>0$ and $y>0$ (or $x<0$ and $y<0$). Then $(1)$ becomes 
  $$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy} \geq 1.$$
  The only solution is to have $\frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
  & {{\sin }^{2}}\theta =\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \right)\ge 1\,\,\,\,\quad,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{x}{y}>0\,\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,\,\theta =k\pi +\frac{\pi }{2}\, \\ 
 & {{\sin }^{2}}\theta =\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \right)\le -1\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\frac{x}{y}<0\,\,\,\,\,\, \\ 
\end{align}$$