# If $x^2 - 2x\cos\alpha + 1 = 0$ and $y^2 - 2y\cos\beta + 1 = 0$, then $2\cos(\alpha + \beta)$ is equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $x^2 - 2x\cos\alpha + 1 = 0$ and $y^2 - 2y\cos\beta + 1 = 0$, then $2\cos(\alpha + \beta)$ is equal to?

**MY ATTEMPT**:
Using the fact that $\cos\alpha$ and $\cos\beta$ must be real, I know that $x$ and $y$ should also be real. As, a result, the discriminant of both the equations should be real. From that I get $\cos\alpha = \cos\beta = \pm 1$.
However, I get stuck here as it forms too many cases for finding $2\cos(\alpha + \beta)$. The answer given here is simply $xy + \frac{1}{xy}$

Please help.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are in general not real, since the discriminant is always non-negative.

Comment: @SangchulLee  cos alpha and beta can be written in terms of x and y respectively. Now, cos alpha and beta need to be real. As a result I get x and y should be real too. 'Kay?

Comment: Just try a simple case where $\alpha = \pi/2$. The first equation reduces to $x^2 + 1 = 0$, which has two imaginary solutions $x = \pm i$. For general $\alpha$, you end up with $x = \cos\alpha \pm i\sin\alpha = \mathrm{e}^{\pm i\alpha}$. Not every polynomial with real coefficients has real zeros.

Answer (score 6):

We have:

$$ x^2-2x\cos\theta+1 = (x-e^{i\theta})(x-e^{-i\theta})$$
hence in your case $x\in\{e^{i\alpha},e^{-i\alpha}\}$ and $y\in\{e^{i\beta},e^{-i\beta}\}$. It follows that
$$2\cos(\alpha+\beta) = e^{i\alpha+i\beta}+e^{-i\alpha-i\beta}$$
is either $xy+\frac{1}{xy}$ or $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: Hi. The answer given is $xy+\frac1{xy}$. I also think $\frac xy+\frac yx$ could also be the answer. Can you please confirm again? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

$$x=e^{\pm i\alpha},y=?$$

If we take the same sign, $$xy=e^{\pm i(\alpha+\beta)},\dfrac1{xy}=e^{\mp i(\alpha+\beta)}$$

Now $e^{iA}+e^{-iA}=2\cos A$

But if we take the opposite sign, $$xy=e^{\pm i(\alpha-\beta)},\dfrac1{xy}=e^{\mp i(\alpha-\beta)}$$

Comment: I don't understand. How can you write x = e^(+- i\alpha)? Please explain.

Comment: @JamilAhmed, Solve for $x$ and use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Answer (score 2):

#### Hint:

$$x^2-2x \cos \alpha+1=0$$
$$\frac D4=\cos^2 \alpha-1\ge0$$
Then $$\cos \alpha= \pm1$$
$$x=\pm1$$

Similarly, $$\cos \beta=\pm1$$
$$y=\pm1$$
$$2\cos (\alpha+ \beta)=2\cos \alpha \cos \beta-2\sin \alpha \sin \beta=$$
$$=2\cos \alpha \cos \beta=\pm2$$

Comment: Put $y=1,$   in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837975/solutions-of-sin2-theta-fracx2y22xy

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, The equation is right for y=1=x. But that is not t he only solution. Is it? in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837975/347297

Comment: @JamilAhmed, true. I'm not sure why  $x,y$ have to be real here!

Comment: If $\beta=\pi$ then $y=-1$, if $\beta=2\pi$ then $y=+1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  Neither am I. I felt that was the right way.

Comment: @JamilAhmed: $x,y \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Roman83, nothing mentioned in the question.